# ':app:dexDebug'. gradle failed 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, build.gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:         org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zumoappname"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aars'
        }   
     }
  }

  dependencies { 
           compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
           compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@jar' 
           compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3' 
           compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0' 
           compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3' 
           compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
           compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' 
  }
```

I can compile and run if I don't use 'com.google.android.gms:play-    services:8.3.0', but that defeats the purpose of my app. Tried multidexenabled. Tried clean and rebuild. Any advice would be appreciated?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@jar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

}

Comment: Just added your comment in the original post.

Comment: Use ./gradlew assemble --info to get the stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your method count has exceed from 65K.
Here is the solution of your problem.

Step:1 enable multidex support

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Step:2 Add These 2 lines

```
 dependencies {
        ...
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }
```

Step:3(a) Change in manifest

```
 <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
```

Step:3(b) If you have your own custom Application class then initialize MultiDex like this.

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dhuma1981 could you please explain about the 3rd step? Where should I insert that android:name? and what is a custom Application class?

Comment: @Srichakradhar There is <application> tag in your AndroidManifest.xml add that name:"..." string there and if you have created your own custom class which inherit Application class then do as shown in step 3(b).

Comment: When I add compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' the appdex error comes back again, this time Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3. Any thoughts?

Comment: Solved second Appdex issue with :Add this to your android closure of build.gradle:

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if you have play-services version 8.3.0 in `android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.3.0`. If not, downloading it might fix the issue.